# Java Thread Safety v Displaying a Dialog from separate Thread

Tags: multithreading, swing, repaint

Hi noticed some code in our application when I first started Java programming.  I had noticed it created a dialog from a separate thread, but never batted an eye lid as it 'seemed to work'.  I then wrapped this method up through my code to display dialogs.

This is as follows:

```
public class DialogModalVisibleThread
        extends Thread {
    private JDialog jDialog;
    public DialogModalVisibleThread(JDialog dialog, String dialogName) {
        this.setName("Set " + dialogName + " Visable");
        jDialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       jDialog.setVisible(true);
       jDialog.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
WarnUserDifferenceDialog dialog = new WarnUserDifferenceDialog( _tableDifferenceCache.size() );
DialogModalVisibleThread dmvt = new DialogModalVisibleThread( dialog, "Warn User About Report Diffs");
dmvt.start();
```

Now, as far as I am now aware, you should never create or modify swing components from a separate thread.  All updates must be carried out on the Event Dispatch Thread.  Surely this applies to the above code?

[EDT on WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)

However, the above code has worked.

But lately, there have been countless repaint issues.  For example, click on a JButton which then calls DialogModalVisibleThread to display a dialog.  It caused buttons alongside the clicked button not to redraw properly.

The repaint problem is more frequent on my machine and not the other developers machine.  The other developer has a laptop with his desktop extended onto a 21" monitor - the monitor being his main display.  He is running Windows 7 with Java version 1.6.0_27.

I am running on a laptop with Windows 7 and Java version 1.6.0_24.  I have 2 additional monitors with my desktop extended onto both.

In the meantime I am going to upgrade to Java 1.6 update 27.

I wondered if the above code could cause repaint problems or are there any other people out there with related paint issues?

Are there any easy ways to diagnose these problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you're breaking a rule, having problems, and wondering if these problems could be cause by the fact that you broke the rule. The answer is Yes. Respect the rules!

To detect the violations, you might be interested by the following page: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/02/16/debugging-swing-final-summary

Comment: +1, indeed Boro.  Thanks JB, I have created a sample project based on the CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager in the link.  Sure enough, start a show a dialog in a separate thread, I get the stack trace indicating there is an issue.  Wrap the invokeLater in the Thread run and no problems.  Interestingly, I put the CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager in our application.  As soon as I run it the Output window in Netbeans is filled up - stack traces are constantly been output.  Sounds like a nightmare task we have to look at. :-(  Cheers andez

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check if your problems are being caused by breaking the rules is to fix them (You should fix them anyway :-)

Just use SwingWorker.invokeLater() from the thread you want to update to UI from to easily adhere to Swing's contract. Something like this should do the trick:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        jDialog.setVisible(true);
        jDialog.requestFocus();        
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: You should make the 'jDialog' variable final for this to work.

Comment: Hi Jesper, thanks for that.  I am aware of the invokeLater - the fact was the code was as is.  It had been specifically written to execute on a separate thread for whatever reasons.  Just these repaint issues have reared there ugly heads now and not before.  Only on some machines.  Sometimes on others.  But the golden rule of swing has been broken - several times it would appear.

Comment: @Andez: Your original code was written to show a modal dialog box that would not interfere with other such modal dialog boxes--each running in its own thread. I did this with really great results. Worked perfectly. But I finally lost my nerve and rewrote it. (If I could remember _how_ I fixed it, I'd add a real answer. But the original was simpler.)